# CSS Selectors performance issues

Tags: css

I noticed that `transitions` lags if we have long selected tree of DOM in one selector.

Like:

```css
#wrapper #content #box-container #boxer .box:hover .transition { 
    /* styles here */
}
```

Otherwise, If i use selector like this:

```css
.box:hover .transition {
    /* styles here */
}
```

It works fine and does not lag
.
Is this true or issue is my document set up?

Comment: Anything to the left of an ID should be removed in 99.9% of all cases.

Comment: A post on CSS Efficiency: http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/

Comment: @ashley i will read it ;)

Comment: @ashley I read it but nothing special. Just he recommends to have IDs.

Comment: then what is it you want to know exactly? if you have multiple `ID`'s then of course rendering will be slower

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS3 effects, that includes transitions, animation, text-shadows etc, is based on browsers, some leave animations on GPU which will lag your animations if the GPU performance is not optimal. If the browsers don't use GPU they leave it on CPU, which will be at it's worst, so if it is lagging it is probably the GPU or CPU and not the DOM, yea obviously if you've too many nested class rules it will be pain for the browser to parse and also hits for performance, so avoid too many nested rules in your CSS

Chrome handles these better than compared to Firefox

If you want I am using heavy animation in one of the [project](http://www.quratek.com/projects/neonize/) I made, open it using firefox and chrome and see the difference, firefox will suck out all the power of your CPU while chrome will be handling it pretty normal

Comment: @AspiringAqib hahaha just look at the difference in 2 browsers and do keep your task manager open

Comment: I don't need to open task manager by `ALT+CTRL+DELETE`, my Lappy already start screaming when i opened your website with Firefox.

Comment: @AspiringAqib See that shows, firefox is bad in handling these where chrome gets smart

Comment: well, what should i do for my users? I can't tell them to open my website in Chrome instead of Firefox.

Comment: @AspiringAqib That's what I told you, don't use excessive CSS3 especially animations, transitions and shadows are way good but that too not excessive

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24569/discussion-between-aspiring-aqib-and-mr-alien)

Answer (score 2):

An ID should exists only once on a page, so this will be sufficient:

```css
#boxer .box:hover .transition { 
    /* styles here */
}
```